# Can you return the parsed JSONProvider result as a Model object to use in the view for MVC?

Tags: f#, type-providers, f#-data

So I have the following F# method

```
static member ReadInstagramSearch() =
    let data = Http.Request( "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=SomeUSer&client_id=someclientid" )
    let res = FsUserSearch.Parse(data)

    res.Data.[0]
```

If I have a C# controller that I call this method with is there anyway to use that result in the View? I've tried just simple access with

```
@Model.FirstName
```

but that gives me an exception

```
'FSharp.Data.RuntimeImplementation.JsonDocument' does not contain a definition for 'FirstName'
```

Is my only option to turn that JsonDocument into a strongly typed Model object? And then return that?

This is using
http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/JsonProvider.html

And my JsonProvider is defined as

```
type FsUserSearch = JsonProvider<"""
{
    "data": [{
        "username": "jack",
        "first_name": "Jack",
        "profile_picture": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_66_75sq.jpg",
        "id": "66",
        "last_name": "Dorsey"
    }]
}""">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly, this is not supported at the moment. The JSON type provider uses *erased types* which means that the parsed document is represented as a value of type `JsonDocument` that does not actually have any of the members that you can see in F#. The F# compiler understands this, but they are not present in compiled code and other languages do not support type providers at the moment.

There is a number of ways to fix this and it is certainly on the TODO list. (It is a bit tricky, implementing `ICustomTypeDescriptor` would work in some scenarios, but not here. Generating actual types might be a way forward. For more information, see [this bug at F# Data GitHub page](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data/issues/134).)

For now, you might be able to use the dynamic access operations that the JSON library provides. See [the JSON Parser and Reader page](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/JsonValue.html) for more details. I think `@Model.FirstName` could be done using:

```
@Model.GetProperty("FirstName").AsString()
```

Certainly not perfect - but sadly C# does not support type providers, so this is probably the best option. Another workaround would be to define a simple F# record type and transform the data you need into a record type that you can then easily use from C#.

Comment: OK that's what I figured. I'm in the process of learning F# so was curious if there was a feature I was unaware of.. I tried the extension method a little bit and C# really didn't seem to like them. I added a using to "FSharp.Data.Json.Extensions" and it complained about the DLL being referenced in both the FSharp.Data.DesignTime and the FSharp.Data dlls. That extension works fine from F# but not in the C# side. So I'll probably go the record type but I was hoping to be lazy :-) But I guess with my new F# knowledge I can make them faster now and with less ceremony. Thanks for the fast reply!!!

Comment: I think records are the easiest option... As for the DLLs, the C# part should only need `FSharp.Data.dll` (the `DesignTime` is just for type providers and should not be needed in the C# project at all - but perhaps Visual Studio copies it there, which might confuse ASP.NET in some way...)

Comment: Yea it came along with the nuget package when I added it that way... Compiles nicely without it.  Records turned out to work well and I also made use of your JsonToXML F# samples which worked out really nicely for transforming the JSON data into XML data that I could store into XML fields so yay for that :-)